# Can anyone make the rowConfig for cardboard work?

Tags: rally

I'm currently trying to upgrade a custom app from sdk 1.x to new version 2.0rc3. I saw the Task Board app or Custom Board app in the AppCatalogs have ability to group the tasks by WorkProduct, however I have unable to make it work.

I have copied/pasted exactly the given example here and it does not work also.

In the screenshot from this link: https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/x/doc/#!/example/groupable-board
it shows the cardboard grouped by the owner but when I try it, cards item is not sorted into group as expected.

if anyone know how to make it work, please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The swimlanes feature that rowConfig enables is not available in 2.0rc3.  The version x SDK and documentation are not officially released, but we will be releasing a new 2.0 version early in 2015 which will definitely include support for this feature.

In the meantime you can use /apps/x/sdk.js to build apps with the usual caveat that this is not a stable version of the API yet and we make no guarantee that any apps written against it will continue to work.